# Angled Edges with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a problem with Angled Edges where at the bottom of a div which the div will have a background color or image of some sort which is a height of 100% so basically the div would slant at the bottom... but on smaller screens it resizes down and the height of the said div becomes small instead of full height. Is there any way to fix the problem with the div becoming too small on smaller screens?

```css
body {height:100%;}
.quote {
  background: #41ade5;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height:100%;
}
.quote:after {
  background: inherit;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.quote:after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
          transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
          transform-origin: 100%;
}

.quote {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 20% 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

p {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
  <h1>Angled Edges</h1>
  <p>With 2 Pseudo Elements</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please use explicit language in your question. _"[...] at the bottom of a div it would slant [...]"_ What would slant? _"[...] it resizes down to a small box instead of full width [...]"_ What resizes? _"Is there any way to fix this?"_ FIx what?

Comment: Is it not just a problem of needing to set 100% height on `html` as well?

Comment: @MaxStarkenburg yes